# how to look for element until present in results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate a scenario where I need to look out for an element until it's present in result and after that click on it.once click on it, it will open a new window.

What I am doing wrong or what I am missing here?

```
    <div class="result-container">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="">
        <img src="/app/static/img/br_news.png">
      </div>
    <div class="result-content">
      <div class="header">
          <img class="icon" src="/app/static/img/lexis-sm.png">
        <h1 class="title" title="Philips India launches awareness campaign on the World Asthma Day">
            Philips India launches awareness campaign on the World Asthma Day
        </h1>
```

Code:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//div[@class='result-container']")
public List<WebElement> allResultsContainer;
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='results']/div[@class='search-results']//div[@class='result-content']")
public static WebElement NewsResults; 
@FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='label']")
public static WebElement searchAuthor;

public void searchforauthoronline() throws InterruptedException { 
    for(WebElement resultElement : allResultsContainer) { 
        log.info("Clicking on original article from search result.");
        resultElement.click(); 
        waitHelper.WaitForElement(searchAuthor, 10); 
        boolean visibility = searchAuthor.isDisplayed();
        if(visibility){ 
            searchAuthor.click(); 
        } 
        else{ 
            System.out.println("Element not present in search result"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code trials by editing your question. It's not easily readable in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, hope now it's readable.

Comment: Did you initialize fields annotated with `@FindBy`? In other to do that, you have to use `PageFactory` class. Otherwise, the annotated elements will be `null`

Comment: Can you explain the problem further? Is there anything not working with your code? If this is the case, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: yes, I have initialized

Comment: @NicoHaase The main problem is that the loop is not iterating, it's only clicking on the first result.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug that problem? Have you checked whether the XPath selector matches more than one result? In the given HTML markup, there is only one element with that class `result-container`

Comment: If I am correct you might be getting staleElementException when you try to click the 2nd element in the loop

Comment: What is `WaitForElement()` doing? If it's not waiting for clickable, that's probably the problem. You also need to edit your question and post the error message you are getting or explain what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

### Are you waiting *before* starting the loop?

You didn't really explain in the question, but according to your comment, the loop only iterates once. I'm guessing because at the time the method is called there is only one element to iterate through.

Your question would imply you need to wait for the element to show up, in which case a `for` loop is the wrong tool for the job. You should probably use a `do/while` loop that keeps looping until it finds the element at which point you can break out of the loop.

I would also recommend adding a fail-safe condition so that the loop doesn't run forever.

In pseudocode it would look something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
int counter = 0;
do {
    sleep for a second
    check the page for all the elements
    if (correctElement.isDisplayed()) {
        correctElement.click();
        found = true;
    }
    counter++;
} while !found && counter <= 30
```

There will be more to it, like rechecking the page for all the elements and identifying the right element, but you should get the idea.